# Avplayer implement subtitles using .srt file in iOS swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem, avplayerlayer

How to implement subtitles using .srt file with avplayer in iOS. When using the avplayer is there a way to use .srt file in avplayer to show the subtitle on the player

Comment: How to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just put .srt file in your AVPlayer and show them.
If you can put subtitles inside your .m3u8 HLS stream on server side - this will be the solution to handle subtitles by AVPLayer automatically.

Until then - I'm using this [library](https://github.com/mhergon/AVPlayerViewController-Subtitles)

Very simple to use and is handling all for you.

Comment: Thanks. This is working only for avplayerviewcontroller but our requirement is show the subtitle over the AVPlayer. how can get player.addSubtitles()

Comment: @AlokKumar I'm also using just AVPlayer with this library. If you have a class, for example VideoPlayer.swift and there is your AVPlayer item, the best way is to make extension like VideoPlayer+Subtitles.swift - https://codeshare.io/anyENY . And then call it like here - https://codeshare.io/5go7NB from you VideoPlayer.swift class.

Comment: Sorry for such a mess comment. If you won't deal with that - I'll update my original answer.

Comment: @AlokKumar Also, don't forget about periodic time observer. I hope you already implemented it. If not - https://codeshare.io/2E8gbv

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH OMG. I have been on a project FOR WEEKS. Trying to find a way to control captions that come separately from video files. Your additional codeshares were very helpful to someone with purely SwiftUI experience. This post is like gold to me. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexHartford do you think you could share that SwiftUI implementation? 

Comment: @JordiBruin 95% of my implementation came from adaptations of the codeshares posted by Pete.

Comment: @PeteStreem if i use this library in my app can i upload my app on app store?

Comment: @AlexHartford if i use this library in my app can i upload my app on app store?

Comment: @AminRezaew check LICENSE file. Most probably you can do it.